# stylesheet_link_tag or @import

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

First of all, I should say I'm newbie in Ruby on Rails. As far as I understand I can include a new css-file on a page using either stylesheet_link_tag in template (I use Slim templates):

```
 = stylesheet_link_tag 'common.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

or @import in CSS:

```
 
    /* application.css */

    @import "common.css";
```

Which way is better? Which way gives higher download speed and will be more convenient for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [these example projects](http://www.opensourcerails.com/), see how they organize it, and read [Rails Asset Pipeline Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).